# Joint Default Probability Range Minimum

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Hi I am having some trouble understanding the min value of the the range for this given question.

Assume that bond A defaults at prob 50% and bond B defaults at a prob 30%. Then what is the range of probability such that at least one bond defaults.

I understand that the max of the range is 80% - here assume that if Bond A defaults then bond B does not. Hence we can summate the probabilities since they share no overlap.

However the Author of the question then states that to determine the minimum assume that when bond A defaults, B does as well - hence we have a minimum value of 50%. This is what confuses me, because couldn’t we then likewise assume the case where if bond B defaults then A defaults as well giving us a min probability of 30% instead of 50%.

And since we are seeking the range - shouldn’t we opt for the minimum value here?

Comment: It is probably a typo: the case to be considered is indeed "if B defaults, then so does A." But remember that you are looking for the probability that *at least one bond defaults*, which is 50% here.

Comment: So if I am understanding this properly, we choose 50% because it encompasses the possibility that bond B defaults as well as A?

Answer (score 3):

We start with the union of the two events A and B. $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. Inserting the given values: $P(A\cup B)=0.5+0.3-P(A\cap B)$. To obtain the minimum the probability of the union, the intersection has to be as large as possible. This is the case, when the smaller set is a subset of the larger set. The corresponding Venn diagram is

[image]

The intersection then is set B. So we subtract $0.3$ and obtain the minimum: $P(A\cup B)=0.5+0.3-0.3=0.5$

> when bond A defaults, B does as well

This is true, since B is a subset of A. The converse is not true.

Comment: Basically $\max\{\mathsf P(A), \mathsf P(B)\}\leqslant \mathsf P(A\cup B)\leqslant\min\{1, \mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)\}$